# why do I keep getting this error: undefined method new_message_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I made a quick ruby on rails app (railstutorial twitter clone). My source code is the same as https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed.

Then I tried adding replies to the messages with http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry?view=asciicast. My comment is at the bottom BigBoy1337. This is what it says:

I keep getting an error saying

```
undefined method `new_message_path'
```

This is in `app/views/messages/_messages.html.erb`

for

```
<%= link_to "Reply", new_message_path(:parent_id => message) %> 
<% if current_user?(message.user) %>
<%= link_to "delete", message, method: :delete,
                     confirm: "You sure?",
                     title: message.content %>
<% end %>
```

Any idea where to define new_message_path? I tried adding

```
def new_message_path
end
```

in `app/controllers/message/controllers`

...but it didn't work. I have downloaded the source code (https://github.com/BigBoy1337/railscasts-episodes/tree/master/episode-262/messenger-after) and that works! but I cant find where they define new_message_path, yet it works. Why does it work for them, and how can I get it to work for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a resource route. Try adding the following to routes.rb:

`resources :messages`

Also, read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: @Kyle I'm sorry, man, but I have to kill you in order to restore balance to the universe

Answer (score 1):

`new_message_path` is defined in `routes.rb`.

Look for this line:

```
resources :messages
```

read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to learn about rails routing.